# Do I need to change the CNAME entries for moving a custom domain served blogger blog to another domain? (NOT changeing registrar, just DNS services)

Tags: domain-name-system

Some customer has GoDaddy as registrar and as DNS services provider for some domain of theirs. They also have a blog at blogger for which they have setup the zone file to contain the required verification entries for the custom domain. We have decided that they will keep GoDaddy as registrar but we want to transfer the DNS service to our own servers. So I got the zone file and I setup the domain configuration in my servers. Before I tell their admin to change the nameservers at the registrar to point to my nameservers, I would like to know if the CNAME entries have to change:

Do I have to login to the blogger and redo the proccess for the custom domain or just copying the same CNAME entries will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change anything. Google's verification is tied to Google user accounts, not to nameservers.

I once verified several of my own sites at once, and found that the verification string was identical for all of them, demonstrating that it refers only to my Google account and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i understood your question right but I don't see how you would need to change CNAME when moving DNS. It should work. CNAME is just an alias.

Comment: blogger uses cname entries to verify that you own the domain to which you want the blog URL to point to. You are right about cnames but maybe they also check if DNS server has changed and if so, they might require a new cname entry. those cnames contain special long names, like keys or something

Comment: Yes, I know and that doesn't have to be done through a CNAME. If I'm not mistaken you can you TXT record to confirm your domain. It will work just fine, it's a cname.

Comment: Well, the instructions on blogger say that you should put some CNAME entries for the purpose of verification. I dont now so much as to be sure that they will also accept TXT, but anyway, my question essentially is if I have to renew those cname or txt values when the domain nameservers change. They may lock/combine those entries with the domain nameservers, so that when someone move DNS hosting they have to enter new cname/txt values. I dont want the risk of downtime due to this possibility. Fear of the unknown :)